# Adding span in JavaScript code to change color of displayed number

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question with my Html/Javascript code. We have to do the "website" which ask you for two numbers, and when you type them into window.prompt they should be displayed green or red if positive/negative. We have to do that using SPAN and CSS code to change the color.

Here is my problem, I actualy don't know how to insert SPAN into my JavaScript code which is:

```
a=window.prompt("What is your first number?"); 
b=window.prompt("What is your second number?");
document.writeln("First number is:\n" + a);
document.writeln("Second number is:\n" + b);
```

Can anyone help me with it please? I have been trying to add this part:

```
document.writeln("First number is:" + <span Class="negative"> + a + </span>);
```

But this is not working. I would love if anyone can help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with quotation marks:

```
document.writeln("First number is:" + <span Class="negative"> + a + </span>);
```

should be:

```
document.writeln("First number is: <span Class=\"negative\">" + a + "</span>");
```

you can use \" to escape quotation inside a string, or use simple quotes:

```
document.writeln('First number is: + <span Class="negative">' + a + '</span>');
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/MWS1a0cKC3XM8sf5xLXk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot!

How should i do that website will automaticly change the color of number if it is positive or negative?

To be more specific: When I type in 5 and - 4 they sould be displayed green(5) and red(-4). I guess i have to add IF CASE somewhere somehow but i have no idea where.

Thanks in addition.